# Rendering nested collections using Backbone.Marionette and Backbone.Relational

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-relational

I'm trying to make a simple calendar/todo-list with Backbone.js.

I have a collection of Days that can each have multiple Todos.
I would like to render each date into an unordered list containing itself an unordered list of todos. Here is my HTML :

```
<ul id="days-list">
    <!-- #day-tpl -->
</ul>

<script id="day-tpl" type="tpl">
    <h1>To-do for {{name}}</h1>
    <ul class="todos-list">
        <!-- todo-tpl -->
    </ul>
</script>

<script id="todo-tpl" type="tpl">
    {{title}}
</script>
```

And here is my JS so far (I have Backbone, Backbone.Marionette and Backbone.Relational included in the HTML).

```
Todo = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({});

Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Todo,
    idAttribute: 'id_todo'
});

Day = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations:[{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'todos',
        relatedModel: 'Todo',
        collectionType: 'Todos',
        reverseRelation:{
            key: 'day',
            includeInJSON: 'id'
        }
    }]
});

Days = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Day
});

TodoView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: '#todo-tpl'
});

TodosView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: TodoView
});

DayView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: '#day-tpl'
});

DaysView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    el: $('#days-list'),
    itemView: DayView
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var days = new Days([
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Monday",
            "todos": [
                {
                    "id_todo": 1,
                    "title": "Learn Javascript"
                },
                {
                    "id_todo": 2,
                    "title": "Learn Node.js"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Tuesday",
            "todos": [
                {
                    "id_todo": 3,
                    "title": "Learn Backbone"
                },
                {
                    "id_todo": 4,
                    "title": "Learn Backbone.Marionette"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]);

    var daysView = new DaysView({collection: days});
    daysView.render();
});
```

The Day collection displays fine (thanks to Marionette !) but I don't know how I'm supposed to render the Todo collections for each day. Any ideas ? Thanks !

EDIT : I've found a way, but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it.

I edited my DayView as follows :

```
DayView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    template: '#day-tpl',
    onRender: function(){
        var $todosList = this.$el.find('.todos-list');
        var todos = new Todos(this.model.get('todos').toJSON());
        var todosView = new TodosView({collection: todos, el: $todosList});
        todosView.render();
    }
});
```

It does render each todo correctly under the right day, but the use of jquery find and toJSON is a code smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marionette has a CompositeView that works best with nested collections.  I've included the documentation and an article that discusses using it.

[Marionette CompositeView documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md)

[Marionette CompositeView Article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/)